# PHP - Spot the problem in this foreach?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session, foreach

I am creating a simple order cart.

In essence, a user clicks order, the products id is added to a session variable ($order) as an array. When viewing the "cart" a check occurs where if a value in the session variable is equal to the id of a specific row in a mysql table, that specific row is returned as an item that was ordered. For each value in the session variable, this process should reoccur.

Here is the bit of code that I am battling with:

```
foreach ($order as $item) 
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($productsSql))
    {
         $itId = $row['id'];
         $itDesc = $row['desc'];
         $itPrice1 = $row['price1'];
         if ($item == $itId) 
        {
        $pageContent .= '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$itDesc.'</td>
                    <td>
                        R'.number_format($itPrice1, 2).'
                    </td>
                </tr>
';      
        }
    }   
}
```

The "$orders" variable is this:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['order']))
{
$_SESSION['order'] = array();
}
```

Can anyone spot any problems with this?

```
$productsQuery = 'SELECT `id`, `refCode`, `desc`, `pack`, `measure`, `quantity`, `deptCode`, `taxable`, `price1`, `price2`, `crdCode`, `cost1`, `cost2` FROM `products` ORDER BY `desc` ';
$productsSql = mysql_query($productsQuery) or die(mysql_error());`
```

Comment: What isn't working or is going wrong?

Comment: No, but maybe you could describe what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: what is `$productsSql` set to? and where is it set?

Comment: Also, do I understand correctly that you loop through all products in the database and only output the ones that are in that array? What if you get a few thousand products in your assortment? This is highly inefficient. `implode` the list of ids into a comma-separated string and use it in your query in the form of: `WHERE id in (<yourListOfIdsGoesHere>)`.

Comment: @Pekka What the problem is, is that when the user goes from the catalog over to the cart, I cannot seem to get the id's of the rows stored in the mysql table to display is they match the values stored in the session.

Comment: @GolzenTrol See my reply to Pekka please.

Comment: @Toby No, I am making my life easier at work :) Or trying to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

mysql_data_seek( $productsSql, 0);

```
foreach ($order as $item) 
{
mysql_data_seek( $productsSql, 0);  //<- this line, to reset the pointer for every EACH.
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($productsSql))
    {
         $itId = $row['id'];
         $itDesc = $row['desc'];
         $itPrice1 = $row['price1'];
         if ($item == $itId) 
        {
        $pageContent .= '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$itDesc.'</td>
                    <td>
                        R'.number_format($itPrice1, 2).'
                    </td>
                </tr>
';      
        }
    }   
}
```

hope that helps

Comment: @Phoenix `Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysql_data_seek() in /pathto/orders/orders-finalize.php on line 45` Any ideas?

Comment: @BlackberryFan mysql_data_seek($productsSql, 0);

Answer (score 3):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($productsSql))
```

This will not be reproduced every `$item`, so save the rows in an array before foreach and replace this `while` with `foreach`.

Comment: There are over 4000 rows in the table :/

Comment: @BlackberryFan .. If each row takes 10KB in memory, 4000 rows is less than 50KB of memory.

Comment: @pst Okay thanks, that does make sense, but in lamens terms, how could I go about this? (i am not a professional developer, just a man with a mission)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified the contents of `$productsSql`, but the line containing it looks wrong.

If `$productsSql` contains SQL code then it won't work at all, because `mysql_fetch_assoc()` requires a database resource. To get a resource, you need to call `mysql_query()` with your SQL code.

Assuming you have called `mysql_query()` outside of the code you've quoted, and `$productsSql` does contain the resulting resource, it's still wrong, because you're looping through the database results multiple times (because of the `foreach` loop), but without resetting or requerying.

The upshot of this is that after the first iteration of the `foreach`, the `while` loop will have run through all the results in the database query, and will be set to the end of the result set. Looping back to the top of the code won't change the position of the result set, so the first time it tries to call `mysql_fetch_assoc()` in the second loop through, it will say "I've already finished", and nothing will happen.

If you want the same set of results to be processed with each iteration of the `foreach` loop, then you need to reset the DB pointer before starting the `while` loop. This can be done with the [`mysql_data_seek()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php).

This will probably achieve what you want, with the code you've provided.

However, this may not be the most efficient way of achieving your desired result. Unfortunately, it's hard to be any more specific how to improve it without seeing more of your code (in particular, the SQL query and more of your data structure).

[EDIT] After the OP added the SQL query to the question, we can see more clearly what the best course of action is.

A quick and dirty fix would indeed be to use `mysql_data_seek()` as I explained above (and as shown in code by @Phoenix), but while this will make the program work, it will be very inefficient, especially as more products are added to the database.

What is actually required is a complete change around of the code, starting with the SQL query itself.

The query needs to be changed to only include the items that are actually wanted. This would be done using a `WHERE` clause, so the query could look something like this:

```
SELECT <lots of fields> FROM products WHERE id IN(5,7,9,<etc>)
```

This is easy to produce, since `$orders` appears to be an array of item IDs, so you can simply use `implode(',',$orders)` to make a list of IDs suitable for the `WHERE` clause. (you would need to be absolutely certain that they were all numeric IDs, though, because anything else would break the SQL query; if you're not sure, you should SQL escape them first).

Once you've got that list, the best approach is to load the DB values into a memory array, and then use your `foreach($order)` loop to grab the appropriate array element.

So your final code would look something like this:

```
$productsQuery = 'SELECT `id`, `refCode`, `desc`, `pack`, `measure`, `quantity`, `deptCode`, `taxable`, `price1`, `price2`, `crdCode`, `cost1`, `cost2` FROM `products` WHERE id IN('.implode(',',$orders).')';
$productsSql = mysql_query($productsQuery) or die(mysql_error());`

$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($productsSql)) {
    $data[$row['id']] = $row;
}

foreach($order as $item) {
   $pageContent .= '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$row[$item]['desc'].'</td>
                <td>
                    R'.number_format($row[$item]['price'], 2).'
                </td>
            </tr>
    ';
}
```

Comment: please view this question for the full code, incidentally, noone answered it as it was too long, but should provide you with a bigger outlook on this matter, if you'd like to help. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974452/creating-an-order-cart-array-variable-not-getting-carried-over-to-final-page

Comment: @BlackberryFan: For a quick+dirty fix, use `mysql_data_see()` (@Phoenix showed you how; and I explained why). But looking at your SQL query, I see that you're loading your entire products table and looping through the whole thing every time. This is very inefficient, especially when you start having more than just a few products. You should reformat your query using a `WHERE` clause so it only selects products which the user has actually added to the basket. I'll add a paragraph to my answer to show you.

Comment: Don't dissappear man, this sounds very interesting. I am very new to php and mysql, so it'll take some time to really process what you're talking about. I do see the importance of what you are saying though, could you provide me with a breif example of the reformatted query please?

Comment: hopefully the code I've just posted will help you. (but I will need to disappear soon.... sorry!)

Comment: Thank you so much! It does indeed help alot. Don't be sorry, I am so happy :) It has been so many days now... Yay!

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1`

Comment: The array $order outputs like this : `array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "4" }` This is with one item ordered.